# How to solve the issue of a program running for an extended period

Tags: c

I was asked to write a code to find the narcissistic number with N digits (3<=N<=7), but I always have the timeout problem when I input 7. What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int narcissistic(int num,int n);
int main(){
    int n;
    int i,min,max;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    max=pow(10,n)-1;
    min=pow(10,n-1);
    for(i=min;i<=max;i++){
        if(nacissistic(i,n)){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int narcissistic(int num,int n){
    int renum=num,sum=0;
    int digit;
    while(renum!=0){
        digit=renum%10;
        renum=renum/10;
        sum+=pow(digit,n);
        if(sum>num){
            break;
        }
    }
    return(sum==num);
}
```

I have tried to convert the data type from int to double, but it didn't work.

Comment: This is not an example of a _timeout_ problem - your program isn't _waiting_ for anything.

Comment: Aside: it's usually a mistake to use `pow()` with integer arithmetic. At the least you should use `(int)round(pow(digit,n))`. But for a time critical online challenge you might like to use a lookup table of xⁿ.

Comment: What do you mean with the sentence _but it didn't work_.  Did it the same thing as before? what did it before?  :)  BTW, what's a narcisistic number?  Are there also psycopathic numbers?

Answer (score 2):

**Narcissist numbers**

If we speak about n digits, then k is a narcissist number, if:

- it has n digits
- k = sum(digit^n)

Most importantly, let's use a lookup table, so you will do the digit powering exactly 9 times rather than n * (10^(n+1) - 10^n) times. Of course, I've fixed the typos as well:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int narcissistic(int num,int n, int *lookup);
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int lookup[10] = {
        0,
        (int)round(pow(1,n)),
        (int)round(pow(2,n)),
        (int)round(pow(3,n)),
        (int)round(pow(4,n)),
        (int)round(pow(5,n)),
        (int)round(pow(6,n)),
        (int)round(pow(7,n)),
        (int)round(pow(8,n)),
        (int)round(pow(9,n))
    };
    int i,min,max;
    max=pow(10,n)-1;
    min=pow(10,n-1);
    for(i=min;i<=max;i++){
        if(narcissistic(i,n, lookup)){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int narcissistic(int num,int n, int *lookup){
    int renum=num,sum=0;
    int digit;
    while(renum!=0){
        digit=renum%10;
        renum=renum/10;
        sum+=lookup[digit];
        //sum+=pow(digit,n);
        if(sum>num){
            break;
        }
    }
    return(sum==num);
}
```

I did some benchmarking between the initial implementation and the lookup table improvement, via:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
int narcissistic(int num,int n, int *lookup, int mode);
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    clock_t powerTic = clock();
    int lookup[10] = {
        0,
        (int)round(pow(1,n)),
        (int)round(pow(2,n)),
        (int)round(pow(3,n)),
        (int)round(pow(4,n)),
        (int)round(pow(5,n)),
        (int)round(pow(6,n)),
        (int)round(pow(7,n)),
        (int)round(pow(8,n)),
        (int)round(pow(9,n))
    };
    clock_t powerToc = clock();
    int i,min,max;
    max=pow(10,n)-1;
    min=pow(10,n-1);
    printf("Without lookup:\n");
    clock_t tic = clock();
    for(i=min;i<=max;i++){
        if(narcissistic(i,n, lookup, 0)){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    clock_t toc = clock();
    printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("With lookup:\n");
    tic = clock();
    for(i=min;i<=max;i++){
        if(narcissistic(i,n, lookup, 1)){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    toc = clock();
    printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)((toc - tic) + (powerToc - powerTic)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
int narcissistic(int num,int n, int *lookup, int mode){
    int renum=num,sum=0;
    int digit;
    while(renum!=0){
        digit=renum%10;
        renum=renum/10;
        if (mode) sum+=lookup[digit];
        else sum+=pow(digit,n);
        if(sum>num){
            break;
        }
    }
    return(sum==num);
}
```

And the difference is quite large. This is the output:

```
Without lookup:
1741725
4210818
9800817
9926315
Elapsed: 1.346095 seconds
With lookup:
1741725
4210818
9800817
9926315
Elapsed: 0.291491 seconds
```

Note that if n = 1, then 0 is missed. You might want to cope with that situation, like setting min to be 0 if n is 1.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe more simple code, I tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool isNarcissistrc(int num) {
  int originalNum = num;
  int n = static_cast<int>(log10(num)) + 1;
  int sum = 0;

  while (num > 0) {
    int digit = num % 10;
    sum += pow(digit, n);
    num /= 10;
  }

  return sum == originalNum;
}

void findNarcissisticNumbers(int digits) {
  for (int i = pow(10, digits-1); i < pow(10, digits); ++i) {
    if (isNarcissistic(i)) {
      std::cout << i << " is a narcissistic number.\n";
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int digits;
  std::cout << "Enter the digits: ";
  std::cin >> digits;

  findNarcissisticNumbers(digits);

  return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions feel free to add comment.

Comment: Using C++ for a question only ever tagged C is not good etiquette.

Comment: I think a C++ - styled simplification of the code will not solve the performance problem mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, despite you don't say what a narcissistic number is (i had to debug your code to guess) your code works well in my system, producing correct answers (despite of using the math `pow()` function, which should give correct result ---except if you pass the 2^53 precision limit, which is not the case---)

I have reduced your code to the more readable one following it (the compiler will not bill you for the number of spaces you use)  I have added a fast power calculation function, working with `long unsigned` numbers, to allow full 64 bit precission.  And the result is this (it produces the same results as given in other answers):

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned long fast_pow(unsigned long num, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned long result = 1UL;
    unsigned mask = ~(~0U >> 1);  /* 0b100000...00000 */

    while (mask) {
        result *= result;
        if (n & mask) {
            result *= num;
        }
        mask >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
} /* fast_pow */

int narcissistic(int num, int n)
{
    int renum = num, sum = 0;
    int digit;

    while(renum != 0 && sum <= num){
        digit = renum % 10;
        renum = renum / 10;
        sum  += fast_pow(digit, n);
    }
    return sum == num;
} /* narcissistic */

int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    unsigned long i, min, max;

    scanf("%ld",&n);
    min = fast_pow(10UL, n - 1UL);
    max = fast_pow(10UL, n) - 1UL;
 
    for(i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        if(narcissistic(i, n)) {
            printf("%lu\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
} /* main */
```

Answer (score -3):

This answer will be easy to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Function to count the number of digits in a given number
int countDigits(int number) {
  int count = 0;
  while (number != 0) {
    number /= 10;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

// Function to check if a number is a narcissistic number
int isNarcissistic(int number) {
  int originalNumber = number;
  int numDigits = countDigits(number);
  int sum = 0;

  while (number > 0) {
    int digit = number % 10;
    sum += pow(digit, numDigits);
    number /= 10;
  }

  return (sum == originalNumber);
}

// Function to find narcissistic numbers of given digits
void findNarcissisticNumbers(int digits) {
  printf("Narcissistic numbers %d digits:\n", digits);
  for (int i = pow(10, digits-1); i <= pow(10, digits); ++i) {
    if (isNarcissistic(i)) {
      printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int digits;

  printf("Enter the digits: ");
  scanf("%d", &digits);

  findNarcissisticNumbers(digits);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer works correctly and is useful.

Comment: Does it solve the problem? If yes, how?

Comment: @anatolyg you can test this code easily on onecompiler.com. It works absolutely.